# How to integrate the Force field to find $x(t)$?

Tags: integration, derivatives, vector-fields

**Problem**: Let the force field $\vec{F}$ be given by,

$$\vec{F}(\vec{x}) = \dfrac{1}{x_{1}^{2} + x_{2}^{2}} \binom{2}{4}$$

Compute the integral of the force field along the circle of radius $r$ centered at the origin.

- (a) First determine $\vec{x}(t)$ and $\dot{\vec{x}}(t)$.
- (b) Compute the integral along the curve from $E(r/0)$ to $W(-r/0)$ oriented counterclockwise.
- (c) Compute the integral along the curve from $N(0/r)$ to $S(0/r)$ oriented clockwise.

===========================================================

Now I know that I have to find $\vec x(t) $ and $\vec x \dot x (t) $ 
And I think that I'd have to integrate $\vec F $($\vec x $) to find $\vec x(t) $. And I think I have to differentiate it to find $\vec x \dot x (t) $
I can't figure out how to do the accent here so I'll post a picture for clarity purpose.

Problem is that I can't integrate $\vec x (t) $ nor differentiate $\vec x \dot x (t) $. Is it possible to do it with 2 variables?
I'd appreciate some tips you can help me.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better in the Physics SE?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: What is (what is the role) of $\binom{2}{4}$? Can we just say that this is a constant?

Comment: @zoli That's a vector; that gives the direction for the force vector.

Comment: $x=(x_1,x_2)$ and $F(x)=(\frac{2}{x_1^2+x_2^2},\frac{4}{x_1^2+x_2^2})$.

Comment: @Botond It's from my math class though so I thought it should be posted here. Should I also give Physics SE a try? I already got F(x) but I still have a problem with integrating it.

Comment: @zoli it is a direction for the force vector as Botond said.

Comment: @Gigantea8 I would give it a try.